# How to update a Timestamp field in MySql from a Java PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp

My index.html has an `<input type="datetime-local">` field and I need to update a MySql database with whatever value the user selects. My database field is currently a Timestamp. How can I create an update statement that allows me to update the database with this datetime-local value? I've tried many options and my current attempt is shown below; however, this does not work. I am doing this all in Java.

```
String updateStatement = "UPDATE cars SET reservation = ? WHERE uniqueID = ?";

pStmt = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
pStmt.setTimestamp(1, reservation);
pStmt.setTimestamp(2, someUniqueId);
```

Comment: What *exactly* does "this datetime-local value" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

To answer your specific code question (but this is the wrong way to handle appointments/reservations):

```java
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(
    1 ,
    ZonedDateTime
    .of
    (
        LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
    )
    .toInstant()
    .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
)
;
```

## *java.time*

The [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type in MySQL is for tracking a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen from an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, resolving to [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).  This maps to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in standard SQL.

The appropriate match in Java would be [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). This class also represents a moment as seen in UTC, but with finer resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Unfortunately, the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 specification requires support for only one of the three types that track a moment: [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Both `Instant` and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) are optional in JDBC 4.2. So your particular [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) may or may not support `Instant`. This design decision by the JDBC team baffles me. Converting between `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` is utterly simple, and should have been required by JDBC spec.

I am guessing you are letting users pick a date and a time-of-day within a particular time zone. But I'm not sure, as your neglected to detail your inputs.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate, localTime , zoneId ) ;
```

To store in the database, let's adjust from a time zone to UTC (an offset of zero). Convert from `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant`, and then to `OffsetDateTime` with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds represented by the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `Instant` for maximum compatibility across JDBC 4.2 drivers.
```

Do *not* call `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp`. That method is now legacy, for the terrible `java.sql.Timestamp` class. Never use date-time classes outside the `java.time` package. Those legacy classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Call [`PreparedStatement#setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)). The JDBC team has yet to define specific `set…` methods for the various *java.time* classes. Again, a design decision which baffles me. However, we can exchange the *java.time* objects using `setObject`/[`getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,java.lang.Class)).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Tracking appointments

By the way, you mentioned the business problem is making restaurant reservations in the future. For this work, you are taking the wrong approach.

Such future appointments are *not* tracked as moments, are *not* specific points on the timeline. If politicians were to change the offset used by that time zone, your customers expect a restaurant reservation for 7 PM to stay at 7 PM, regardless of politicians moving the clock forward or backward. Similarly, a dental appointment for 3 PM four months from now should stay at 3 PM even if the politicians change the offset. And politicians around the world *do* enjoy changing their time zone offset. This happens surprisingly often, and with less and less forewarning.

Reservations/appointments should be tracked as date and time *without* time zone, storing time zone separately in second column of database. These types would be `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in standard SQL, and `DATETIME` in MySQL. And use a text type for the time zone identifier. The matching type in Java would be `LocalDateTime` and `ZoneId`. At runtime for calendaring, combine to determine a moment with a `ZonedDateTime`.

I and other authors have covered this many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your date format is incorrect.

```
reservation = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

*UPDATE*

Ok,I understand you.You should use `String` to receive the `datetime-local` value.

Because the format of `datetime-local` from frontend is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`, but the format of TimeStamp in Java(package `java.sql`) is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

It lack the `:ss`, so can not receive.

Finally set timestamp after convert String to TimeStamp.

```java
datetimeLocal = datetimeLocal.replaceAll("T", " ") + ":00";
Timestamp reservation = Timestamp.valueOf(datetimeLocal);
```

Comment: I can't use the current time. This field needs to represent a time in the future when a customer has made a reservation for something. For example, the customer has reserved a table at a restaurant, so I want to capture the date and time they selected.